# XAML ListvView display XML Data From an XMLDocument Variable

Tags: xml, wpf, xaml

I am creating a listview to display a complete XML file (the file is quite short so I can display all of it). The listview contains some columns.

I want to load this content from an XMLDocument. I don't want to access the file directly. My design dictates a separation between the UI and the data.

All I know is that I get an XMLDocument containing the complete XML. I want to load this into the ListView.

This is what I am using right now:

```
  <XmlDataProvider x:Key="LeaderboardTestList"
                         x:Name="dataprovider"
                         Source="/xmluitest;component/XMLFile1.xml" />
```

It is loading this from a file. But I want to load this from an XmlDocument so it obeys my design pattern. My UI should have no connection to the file.

Thank you,

Comment: The `XmlDataProvider` has a `Document` property that you can set to an `XmlDocument`.

Comment: Thank you this helped @mm8 if you put this as an answer I will mark as solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `XmlDataProvider` has a `Document` property that you can set to an `XmlDocument`.